# How to write JAX-RS resource for consuming uploaded file

Tags: file-upload, jax-rs

This is my class:

package pkg.rest;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/"
                + fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

this is my Html File for uploading :

```
<html>
<body>


    <h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

    <form action="rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>REST_WS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

when i try to upload file to server then no action perform i dint create client direct run it html file in tomcat server and try to access it please help me what we need to do change this i am writing first time so please help .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put enough stuff in `web.xml`, so the container does not know how to route request to your Jersey servlet.

Add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>pkg.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: we need to create client or direct we run this Project?

Comment: Run this project directly in tomcat

Comment: StandardWrapper.Throwable  excpetion is coming

Comment: and this Exception also came after Uploading image : Allocate exception for servlet UploadServlet

Comment: Are you sure Jersey Jars are in either you tomcat's lib dir or your WEB-INF/lib dir?

Comment: yes am sure asm,jursey,jursymultipart all jar file there in lib folder

Comment: Can you update you question with updated web.xml and the full stack trace?

Comment: its in lib directory i have alredy puted

Comment: jersey-servlet.jar also we need ?

Comment: Yes, basically you need all the jersey jars

Comment: i have added these library :asm-3.3.1.jar
jersey-bundle-1.14.jar
jersey-multipart-1.5.jar
jersey-servlet-1.18.1-sources.jar
json.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar apart from any other jar we need to add?

Comment: I'm not sure, try it out?

Comment: can i have ur email id so that i can send u my code and u pleas just check where i did wrong plz am stucking

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the pattern /rest/* in all the url's which you want to be handled as a service.